# Stiemke's Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Stiemke's Theorem: Only one of the following statements are true:

(a) $Ax\leq 0$ has a solution $x$.

(b) $A^Ty=0$, $y>0$ has a solutions $y$.

I'm trying to understand this theorem. Look at the following example:

$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & -2 \\ -1 & 2\end{matrix}\right]$, $x=\left[\begin{matrix}2\\1\end{matrix}\right]$ and  $y=\left[\begin{matrix}1\\1\end{matrix}\right]$.

Then $Ax=0$ and $A^Ty=0$, which contradicts the theorem. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get that version of the theorem from? [Here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Motzkin_transposition_theorem#Stiemke.27s_theorem) and [here](http://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/stats/courses/MathFinance/Gordan.pdf), the theorem is stated as follows:

Only one of the following statements are true:

(a) $Ax > 0$ has a solution $x$.

(b) $A^Ty=0$, $y>0$ has a solution $y$.

In (a), there is a strict inequality.

Comment: I have seen it with the strict inequality too. Sometimes it's written $<$ instead of $>$ but they are equivalent since there is no restriction on the sign of $x$.

Comment: I found a wrong statement here. http://wwwbiz.meijo-u.ac.jp/SEBM/ronso/no6_4/ozaki.pdf . But it does not make sense to have $Ax \geq 0$ because even the zero vector satisfies that.